# How to create a specific new object from an existing one using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I currently have this array of objects:

```
[{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "valuex"
},{
   "key1": "value3",
   "key2": "value4",
   "key3": "valuey"
}]
```

What I would like to get in the end is an array of strings

```
["value1/value2", "value3/value4"]
```

preferrably using some "lodash magic shortcut".

So essentially, I would like to join the values of key1 and key2 to a string using '/' as a separator while ignoring key3.

I tried a lot using `_.transform` and `_.join` but none of my attempts were even close to the desired result. I know that this is not a free coding service, but maybe you have a hint for me?

Comment: without lodash but equally magic:
yourArray.map(el => `${el.key1}/${el.key2}`) (backticks should be there, but comments section is taking them as styling characters)

Comment: @Gonzalo.- put that in an answer, always good to have a built-in only method of doing something.

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`lodash.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map).

```js
var data = [{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "valuex"
}, {
  "key1": "value3",
  "key2": "value4",
  "key3": "valuey"
}]

console.log(_.map(data, ob => `${ob.key2}/${ob.key2}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh myyyy ... so embarrassingly easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without using lodash, but equally magic (pure vanilla js)

```js
let response = [{
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2",
       "key3": "valuex"
    },{
       "key1": "value3",
       "key2": "value4",
       "key3": "valuey"
    }].map(el => `${el.key1}/${el.key2}`);
    
   console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using Lodash but :

```js
const myArray = [{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "valuex"
},{
   "key1": "value3",
   "key2": "value4",
   "key3": "valuey"
}]

const newArray = myArray.map(element => element.key1 + '/' + element.key2)

console.log(newArray)
```